# How to delete records with lower version in big query?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

Lets say my table contains the following data

| id | name | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rahul | 1 |
| 1 | Rahul | 2 |
| 2 | John | 1 |
| 3 | Mike | 1 |
| 2 | John | 2 |
| 4 | Rubel | 1 |
| 5 | David | 1 |
| 1 | Rahul | 3 |

I need to filter the duplicate records with lower version. How can this be done?
The output essentially should be

| id | name | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rahul | 3 |
| 2 | John | 2 |
| 3 | Mike | 1 |
| 4 | Rubel | 1 |
| 5 | David | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

For this dataset, aggregation seems sufficient:

```
select id, name, max(version) as max_version
from mytable
group by id, name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
select id, name, version
from your_table t
Where not exists
      (Select 1 from your_table tt
        Where tt.id = t.id and tt.version > t.version)
```

Or you can use analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
Select id, name, version from
(select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by id order by version desc) as rn
  from your_table t) t
 Where rn = 1
```